# How can logout foursquare in iphone integration?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, foursquare, logout

How the **`foursquare`** *`Logout`* functionality has to be implemented in iPhone integration application?

I tried this code.But it is not working.

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{

    NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"https://foursquare.com/"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];


    }

}
```

Comment: Crystal Ball Answers: Remove the access token from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: if remove the NSuserDefaults mean, it sign out. But again other user try to login foursquare mean the login in first user id.it's not possible to login other user.

Comment: remove all then. Access token, access token secret, username, whatever is stored.

Comment: i have remove whatever is stored,but not working. how to clear the foursquare cookies?